Zod modular-forms and typescript: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite
Here my zod related code:
import { z } from 'zod';
import type { infer as zodInfer } from 'zod';

export const registrationFormSchema = z.object({
  nom: z.string().min(1, 'El nom és obligatori'),
  dataNaixement: z.string().min(1, 'La data de naixement és obligatòria'),
  telefonContacte: z.string().min(9, 'El telèfon de contacte ha de tenir almenys 9 dígits'),
  telefonEmergencia: z.string().min(9, 'El telèfon d\'emergència ha de tenir almenys 9 dígits'),
}).refine(
  (data) => data.telefonContacte !== data.telefonEmergencia,
  {
    message: 'El telèfon de contacte i el telèfon d\'emergència no poden ser els mateixos',
    path: ['telefonEmergencia'],
  }
);

export type TRegistrationForm = zodInfer<typeof registrationFormSchema>;

export const registrationFormInitialValues: TRegistrationForm = {
  nom: '',
  dataNaixement: '',
  telefonContacte: '',
  telefonEmergencia: '',
};

Here the way I'm using it:
import { createForm, zodForm } from '@modular-forms/solid'
import { registrationFormSchema, type TRegistrationForm, registrationFormInitialValues } from '../schema';

const [form, { Field }] = createForm<TRegistrationForm>({
  initialValues: registrationFormInitialValues,
  validate: zodForm<TRegistrationForm>(registrationFormSchema)
});

It's telling:

Argument of type 'ZodEffects<ZodObject<{ nom: ZodString; dataNaixement: ZodString; telefonContacte: ZodString; telefonEmergencia: ZodString; }, "strip", ZodTypeAny, { ...; }, { ...; }>, { ...; }, { ...; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ZodType<any, any, { nom: string; dataNaixement: string; telefonContacte: string; telefonEmergencia: string; }>'.

I've also tried:
const [form, { Form, Field }] = createForm<TRegistrationForm>({
  initialValues: registrationFormInitialValues,
  validate: zodForm(registrationFormSchema)
});


Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite

I don't quite figure out what's wrong here.
Any ideas?
